# ftp listing display a different formatted time

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

When using the ftp client on Linux (CentOS 7), the modify time is not formatting as desired when using the `ls` command. The modify time when listing files differs from when the file was uploaded.

With Filezilla, the modify time and upload time are the same.

Is there a way to get the ftp client to use the system time when listing files?

Date/time using the FTP command in CentOS 7:

```
[support@cms-t09 ~] ftp 192.168.0.250 
Connected to 192.168.0.250 (192.168.0.250).
220 ProFTPD Server (NETGEAR ReadyNAS) [SUPPORT_NAS] 
Name (192.168.0.250:support): support
331 Password required for support
Password:
230 User supportlogged in
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> cd test
250 CWD command successful
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,250,146,80).
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
226 Transfer complete
ftp> put test.txt
local: test.txt remote: test.txt
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,250,152,211).
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for test.txt
226 Transfer complete
5 bytes sent in 3.6e-05 secs (138.89 Kbytes/sec)
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,250,174,233).
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
-rw-rw-rw-   1 support users           5 Jul 30 22:43 test.txt
226 Transfer complete
```

File zilla display the last modified time in the correct format:
[image]

Date/time on server a few minutes after the upload

```
[support@cms-t09 ~]$ date 
Mon Jul 31 08:45:53 AEST 2023
```

NAS time zone has been set as below:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy & paste examples. If possible also run `ls -l` output  for the corresponding files on the remote system.

Comment: The transfer of metadata is the weak point of the FTP. Simply speaking, the server sends time info using own timezone (seems to be UTC). Some elaborate FTP clients do retrieve the time using additional more reliable ways, but the `ftp` is very basic client.